# Calculus position/velocity question.

Tags: calculus

Disclaimer: I am not a student trying to get free internet homework help.  I am an adult who is learning Calculus.  I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.

Here is the question (Not sure of the best way to format this)

$$s(t)=t^3-9t^2+24t-6$$
Q:  The speed of the particle is decreasing for:

1) t<1

2) t>2

3) t<3

4) t<1 and t>2

5) all t

So, I took the derivative of position to get velocity, and set it to zero.
$$v(t)=3t^2-18t+24=0$$

Now, I have a parabola with roots at (2,0) and (4,0) and vertex (3,-3)

I understand that Speed is DECREASING when either:

a) velocity is (+) and slope is (-)
(I'm moving forward, but velocity is becoming less positive)

b) velocity is (-) and slope is (+)
(I'm moving backwards, but velocity is becoming less negative)

So, MY answer is not in the list $t<2$ and $3<t<4$

$t<2$ is where the parabola meets criterion (a)

$3<t<4$  is where the parabola meets criterion (b)

Yet, the answer key says choice (3) ??
What am I doing wrong?

=====================
Update:

There was another question in the same set that is equally perplexing!

Q:  The minimum value of the speed is:
1) -3

2) -2

3) -1

4) 0

5) 1

MY answer would be 0.  (choice 4), since speed = |v|
Yet, the answer key says choice 3
How could speed OR velocity be equal to -1 ?
Minimum velocity is -3 (choice 1)

Comment: To find when speed is decreasing (the rate of change of speed), don't you need to find the derivative of the velocity?

Comment: @JackOfAll : I'd like to reassure you that your definition of speed as the absolute value of velocity is the correct one.  Assuming Ross's answer is correct (and I have no reason not to), the correct answer is not one of the choices and whoever wrote this problem made a serious, elementary mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the answer key is using velocity instead of speed.  Following your definition of speed as absolute value of velocity, you are correct that it is decreasing on $t \lt 2$, but it is also decreasing on $3 \lt t \lt 4$ (your case b).  That is still not one of the choices.  It looks like you understand the issue, though.

Comment: Do you think the question meant to ask when the VELOCITY is decreasing?

Comment: I suspect that it did, or whoever made the answer key was thinking in that direction.  For the second question, if you interpret speed as velocity the minimum is $-3$  I agree with you that the minimum is $0$.  I can't come up with a reason to support $-1$

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate one more time t0 get the acceleration, $a(t) = 6t-18$. The speed is decreasing when $a(t) <0$, or in other words, when $t < 3$.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the question said "speed is decreasing" NOT "velocity is decreasing".   If it said velocity, I would agree that to find if it's increasing or decreasing, you just take that 2nd deriv.

Comment: @JackOfAll: I can read thank you. People often use speed synonymously with velocity.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's going on here is most likely this:

If the position is given by

$s(t)=t^3-9t^2+24t-6, \tag{1}$

then as you correctly found the velocity is the derivative of $s$:

$v(t)=3t^2-18t+24. \tag{2}$

$v(t)$ is decreasing when $v'(t) < 0$; we have

$v'(t) = 6t - 18, \tag{3}$

so

$v'(t) < 0 \Leftrightarrow t < 3, \tag{4}$

in agreement with your answer key.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Yes, but the question said "speed is decreasing" NOT "velocity is decreasing". If it said velocity, I would agree that to find if it's increasing or decreasing, you just take that 2nd deriv.  Do you think the question meant to ask when the VELOCITY is decreasing?

Comment: @JackOfAll:  yes, I think so; but this assessment is partly based on the correlation between the key's answer and mine!  "Speed" and "velocity" aren't completely disjoint terms, semantically, in my experience; especially my experience with calculus texts! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether the *speed* is decreasing. Speed is a scalar, while velocity is a vector. You need to see where the speed is moving away from zero

$s(t) = t^3 - 9t^2 + 24t - 6$

$v(t) = s'(t) = 3t^2 - 18t + 24$

Set velocity equal to 0 and solve

$0 = 3t^2 - 18t + 24$

$0 = t^2 - 6t + 8$

$0 = (t-4)(t-2)$

From here we can see that the vertex is located at $x=\dfrac{2+4}{2}=3$. The parabola opens upwards because the leading coefficient is positive. However, speed is always positive, and is the absolute value of velocity:

$speed(t) = |v(t)|$

What can we deduce from this?

- The speed is positive and decreasing on $(-\infty,2)$
- The speed is 0 at $x=2$
- The speed is positive and increasing on $(2,3)$
- The speed is constant at $x=3$
- The speed is positive and decreasing on $(3,4)$
- The speed is 0 at $x=4$
- The speed is positive and increasing on $(4,\infty)$

Why is the speed always positive? Because speed is a scalar. Speed is the absolute value of velocity. The speed is therefore decreasing on $(-\infty,2)\cup(3,4)$. **The question is wrong to ask about speed.**

Your question *should* be asking you when ***velocity*** is decreasing. An inspection of the graph will show us that it decreases from $-\infty$ to 3 before it starts going back up again.

But here's the calculus way to get that answer - take the second derivative:

$a(t) = v'(t) = 6t-18$

The *acceleration* shows us the change in velocity. It is negative from $-\infty$ until its zero at $t=3$, which means that velocity is decreasing. That is, the change in velocity is negative.